# Weighted average from an array

Tags: javascript, average, weighted

I have to write the following weighted average formula in JavaScript:

> Average = (p1*p2*x1 + p3*p4*x2 + ... +p(n-2)*p(n-1)*xn) / (p1*p2 + p3*p4 + ... + p(n-2)p(n-1) )

The formula gives the average of `x` values.

I also have an `array` populated with `n` elements in JavaScript:

```
Array = (p1,p2,x1,p3,p4,x2....)
```

...where `pi` are the weights and `xi` the values I want to find the average for.

How can I write the formula using this array?

Comment: Can you give example values please?
Show us a calculation with real world values and the results you expect

Comment: do you really have to have your `p` and `x` values interleaved like that?

Comment: Do you always have 2 p before an x or can it change?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use the following strategy:

- Create two new arrays (probably `weights` and `values`).
- Iterate over the original array in steps of 3; multiplying the `pn`'s and pushing the result into `weights` and pushing the `xn` into `values`.
- Iterate over the new arrays, creating the weighted total (the left hand of the division) and  the total weight (right hand of the division).
- Divide one by the other. Done.

In other words, something like this:

```
function weighted_average(input) {
    var weights = [];
    var values = [];
    var weighted_total = 0;
    var total_weight = 0;;

    if (input.length % 3 !== 0) {
        throw new Error("Input array length is not a multiple of 3.");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += 3) {
        weights.push(input[i] * input[i + 1]);
        values.push(input[i + 2]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < weights.length; i += 1) {
        weighted_total += weights[i] * values[i];
        total_weight += weights[i];
    }

    return weighted_total / total_weight;
}
```

You'll have to verify whether this does exactly what you're after, though. No guarantees. ;)

JSFiddle demo: [jsfiddle.net/Z8seZ](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8seZ/)

Of course, you could skip the intermediary arrays to make it a bit faster. But the above is more explicit and more readable, and therefore more maintainable (e.g. you could easily split out the actual algorithm and create different "wrapper" functions for different forms of input). I would only optimize it if working with (really) large data sets.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a functional approach, requiring ES5:

```
var w = a.unzip(3).map(function(v, i, a) {
    var weight = v[0] * v[1];
    var sum = weight * v[2];
    return [sum, weight];
}).reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
    return [p[0] + c[0], p[1] + c[1]];
}, [0, 0]);

var aw = w[0] / w[1];
```

which in pseudo-code is:

```
split the array into chunks of three
convert each three [p1, p2, x ] into a pair [ p1 * p2 * x , p1 * p2 ]
sum the pairs (along the array, not within each pair)
divide one by the other
```

and where the (non-standard) `unzip` function which chunks the array is:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'unzip', {
    value: function(n) {
        n = n || 2;
        return this.reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
            if (i % n === 0) {
                p.push(a.slice(i, i + n));
            }
            return p;
        }, []);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow. That's impressive. Took me a while to read, though... Are you a Perl programmer? :P

Comment: @PPvG I've dabbled in Perl, but this approach owes more to functional languages like Erlang, Haskell and LISP.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 one-liner for an array of objects `xs` containing the keys `w` as weight and `v` as value:

```
((_w, _v) => _v / _w)(...xs.reduce((r, o) => [r[0] + o[w], r[1] + o[w] * o[v]], [0, 0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner to read solution in TypeScript:

```
.reduce<{ weightedSum: number; sum: number }[]>(
  (a, b) => [
    {
      weightedSum:
        a[0].weightedSum + b.value * b.weight,
      sum: a[0].sum + b.weight,
    },
  ],
  [{ weightedSum: 0, sum: 0 }]
)
.map((value) => value.weightedSum / value.sum)[0]
```

Basically you iteratively calculate the numerator and denominator at the same time, then divide it when it's complete.